# Show cards from one Trello board on another board without duplicating

Tags: trello

We have our normal work in progress board. I want to have some of the cards from the WIP board also appear on another client specific board.

Is there some way to do so without replicating the cards manually on both boards.

Comment: I'm in the need for this too.

Answer (score 8):

As I always wanted this feature, I wrote [a bot](https://cardsync.xyz/) that keeps cards in sync across Boards.

See if it suits your needs. From [the description](https://cardsync.xyz/):

> Hello, my name is cardsync and I am a bot designed to keep cards in sync, 
>   which means I update the content of one Trello card to reflect changes
>   made on other card.

Also, here's a small gif animation that shows it in action:

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect, but unfortunately the link 404s

Comment: @BenHughes Just wanted to let you know, as of today the link isn't dead anymore :)

Answer (score 7):

Trello does not currently have this functionality. You can move cards, but you cannot copy cards or have cards that exist on multiple boards.

You can discuss and advocate / vote for this idea on this card: [Cards live on multiple boards](https://trello.com/c/ugnmoGQ4/17-cards-live-on-multiple-boards).

See the [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development) for more ideas, as well as known issues and upcoming / just-live features.

Answer (score 1):

There's a relatively new Trello feature that does something pretty close to what I understand the objective here to be.

As of ~Sept. 2017, you can attach cards to cards. For the sake of discussion, let's say you attached B and C to A. From the detailed view of A, you see a small preview of B and C, including board & list name, labels, members, etc. You can click on B or C from that detailed view of A, and you're navigated to the original (in the context of B or C's board, if different).

Importantly, this is a dynamic reference, not a copy. So state is naturally maintained. And it does work across boards.

More details about this are at: https://blog.trello.com/related-cards-related-boards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so without replicating cards manually.

In Pintask, there is a "Mirror card" function. It allows to create a card replica with exactly same name, text, members, comments and other properties. When the original card is changed, all its mirrors will reflect the change, too. However, you could move the mirror to another list, or even to another board, while the original card stays in place.

This wiki page provides more info: http://wiki.pintask.me/wiki/Have_cards_from_client_projects_appear_on_unified_company_board

Disclosure: I am Pintask founder.

Comment: Answers that require the reader to follow a link to get any useful information are not good answers.

Comment: As Al has pointed out, please incorporate a summary of what the blog post says in the body of your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointers! I've expanded the answer with more info, so that it does not require the reader to follow the link. Is it good now? Are there any other ways to improve it?

Comment: @jonsca could you please see if the answer is good now? Should I do anything else to improve it?

Comment: This answer is for Pintask, not for Trello.