# Is there a way to allow more than one group of users 'read only' access to a board?

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show cards from one Trello board on another board without duplicating](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26618/show-cards-from-one-trello-board-on-another-board-without-duplicating)

I have two different groups of users that I would like to be able to view one board but not edit or move cards. I currently have one of the groups set up in an organization that the board is a member of.

How can I allow this second group of users the proper access to the board without having them join the other organization (we don't want them to be able to view the other boards in that organization)?

Can a board belong to more than one organization or is there another way to set up this scenario?

Comment: Not a duplicate of the other card. It is really around permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible now, and it's not likely we'll be adding different kinds of user groups in the short term. We're considering features to make usage easier for larger organizations, which might include multi-group or team access.

This would be partially solved by "anyone with the URL" access, which we are tracking as a feature. Email us at feature-ideas@trello.com to express support for that feature.

Comment: I have not seen this card yet on the development board. Has it made it there yet? Thank you.